# NSTextField clicked link colour

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, appkit, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSTextField` that contains an `NSAttributedString` which itself contains a clickable link.

I've change the colour of the link for my own styling, however when I click on it it becomes blue and underlined. How can I stop this?

Comment: What you want to stop? That it is clickable, or the blue color and underline. Do you want it to be clickable? Or do you want another color?

Comment: I want it clickable, but I want to keep the link in my custom styling. I want to stop it going blue and underlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that I'm not the only one with this problem, and there's a handy class to solve it:

https://github.com/laevandus/NSTextFieldHyperlinks

https://github.com/catlan/DSClickableURLTextField

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1487/_index.html) (`http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1487/_index.html`)  may help you. It will show you how to set/change the blue link color and the underlineAttribute. You may also have a look at the methods `-linkTextAttributes` and `-setLinkTextAttributes:` of an NSTextView.

Comment: Hi. As I stated, I know how to set the link colour (using that method), but it doesn't maintain that look when clicked on.