# Restore the visual state of an NSAttributedString after having clicked on it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextfield, nstextview

I need to restore the visual state of an NSAttributedString after having clicked on it.

My NSAttributedString contains links attributed to ranges.

In this example the text "@user" has a a link to "htpp://somesite.com/":

```
let text = "Hey @user!"

let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let range = NSRange(location: 4, length: 5)
attr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.orange, range: range)
attr.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "htpp://somesite.com/", range: range)

let tf = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
tf.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
tf.isSelectable = true
tf.stringValue = text
tf.attributedStringValue = attr
```

It works well: click on "@user" in the text field, it launches the URL.

[image]

**But once clicked, the attributed color disappears and is replaced by this blue one and an underline is added:**

[image]

I can't find a solution to restore the original color once the string is clicked (or to avoid having this automatic change altogether).

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939925/nstextfield-label-attributed-text-select) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366054/nstextfield-clicked-link-colour) but there's no actual solution, and I can't integrate the pointed library to my project (I'd really like to not having to import any library, actually).

Note that my existing code is in Swift but I can use an Objective-C solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the link is clicked, the text is displayed by the field editor. The default link text style in the field editor is blue and underlined.

Solution 1: change the text style of the link in an override of `setUpFieldEditorAttributes:` in a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`.

```
- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj {
    NSText *fieldEditor = [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:textObj];
    if ([fieldEditor isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *linkAttributes = [((NSTextView *)fieldEditor).linkTextAttributes mutableCopy];
        linkAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [NSColor orangeColor];
        [linkAttributes removeObjectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
        ((NSTextView *)fieldEditor).linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes;
    }
    return fieldEditor;
}
```

Side effect: the field editor is shared by all controls in the window and all controls will now show orange links.

Solution 2: substitute your own field editor by using the `fieldEditor:forObject:` method or the `windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:` delegate method of `NSWindow`. The text field has its own field editor and other controls won't have orange links. No subclasses of `NSTextField` or `NSTextFieldCell` required.

Example: (AppDelegate is the delegate of the window)

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTextView *linkFieldEditor;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (NSTextView *)linkFieldEditor {
    if (!_linkFieldEditor) {
        _linkFieldEditor = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
        _linkFieldEditor.fieldEditor = YES;
        NSMutableDictionary *linkAttributes = [_linkFieldEditor.linkTextAttributes mutableCopy];
        linkAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = [NSColor orangeColor];
        [linkAttributes removeObjectForKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
        _linkFieldEditor.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes;
    }
    return _linkFieldEditor;
}

- (id)windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)client {
    if (client == self.textField)
        return self.linkFieldEditor;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Solution 3: create a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`, implement `fieldEditorForView:` and return your own field editor. This is similar to solution 2 but implemented by the cell instead of the window delegate.

Documentation on the field editor: [Text Fields, Text Views, and the Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA) and [Using a Custom Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW35).

Comment: First solution: very nice. The side effect is a bit of a problem, though. Is there a way to get the link itself from there? I would be able to filter its type and set back the right color. // I don't understand your second solution, sorry, if you can explain... :p

Comment: `NSTextFieldCell` also has a property `attributedStringValue`.

Comment: This is really good and offers multiple approaches, I like it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A very weird thing happened: the code in my question doesn't work anymore, the links are always blue even without clicking, so I can't use your solution anymore. Please see [this new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926951/color-attribute-is-ignored-in-nsattributedstring-with-nslinkattributename) if you have a few minutes, I'm very puzzled by this...