# Color attribute is ignored in NSAttributedString with NSLinkAttributeName

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode8, nsattributedstring, nstextfield

In an `NSAttributedString`, a range of letters has a link attribute and a custom color attribute.

In Xcode 7 with Swift 2, it works:

[image]

In Xcode 8 with Swift 3, the custom attributed color for the link is always ignored (it should be orange in the screenshot).

[image]

Here's the code for testing.

Swift 2, Xcode 7:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground

let text = "Hey @user!"

let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let range = NSRange(location: 4, length: 5)
attr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.orangeColor(), range: range)
attr.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://somesite.com/", range: range)

let tf = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
tf.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
tf.selectable = true
tf.stringValue = text
tf.attributedStringValue = attr

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = tf
```

Swift 3, Xcode 8:

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

let text = "Hey @user!"

let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
let range = NSRange(location: 4, length: 5)
attr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.orange, range: range)
attr.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://somesite.com/", range: range)

let tf = NSTextField(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
tf.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
tf.isSelectable = true
tf.stringValue = text
tf.attributedStringValue = attr

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tf
```

I've sent a bug report to Apple, but in the meantime if someone has an idea for a fix or workaround in Xcode 8, that would be great.

Comment: When you use `NSTextView`, you must set the `linkTextAttributes` property. When a `NSTextField` is focused and can be edited, the text is shown in a `NSTextView` which uses its `linkTextAttributes` (default blue, underlined and a hand cursor).

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, unfortunately I've already tried overriding linkTextAttributes, it's a good solution but it applies the same attributes to all links in the attributed string, and I need to be able to set different ones. The thing is, *your answer to my other question worked until recently*, the big mistery here is why the exact same code you answered to doesn't work anymore. :)

Comment: Oh. The link is orange in Xcode 7. It's blue in Xcode 8. I'm filing a radar... Sorry to have bothered you with this, @Willeke...

Comment: `"htpp"`???????

Comment: And the underlining is new too. It used to be have no underline (as your first screen shot shows). Basically they've made the text view link look like a label link. This is probably deliberate; it was pretty confusing before.

Comment: The underlining is not new. It is certainly default on OS X 10.10.

Comment: @matt Just a silly typo, of course. // I've searched for changelogs and didn't find anything. I understand why they would do this on purpose, but I certainly hope there will be a way to change the appearance of these links again...

Comment: I don't know what you mean about the underlining. I don't get underlining on my machine. I've never seen underlining on a UITextView link. I'm not even sure why you've got underlining. I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @matt try `NSTextView`,

Comment: Oh, I see, because you're on the desktop. But the problem with the color happens in UITextView too in iOS 10. You've made an important discovery here. In your bug report please mention that this same issue happen in UITextView in iOS 10.

Comment: @EricAya Do you want a solution for playground or a solution for an app?

Comment: @Willeke I get the same behavior in my current app and in a Playground, it doesn't change anything. If you have a solution, or even just an idea, please go ahead. :) I'm just using the Playground for easy demonstration.

Comment: @EricAya Thanks for doing that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple Developer has answered:

> Please know that our engineering team has determined that this issue **behaves as intended** based on the information provided.

And they explain why it worked before but doesn't anymore:

> Unfortunately, **the previous behavior** (attributed string ranges with NSLinkAttributeName rendering in a custom color) **was not explicitly supported**.  It happened to work because NSTextField was only rendering the link when the field editor was present; without the field editor, we fall back to the color specified by NSForegroundColorAttributeName.
>
> Version 10.12 updated NSLayoutManager and NSTextField to render links using the default link appearance, similar to iOS. ([see AppKit release notes for 10.12.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html))
>
> To promote consistency, the intended behavior is for ranges that represent links (specified via NSLinkAttributeName) to be drawn using the default link appearance.  So the current behavior is the expected behavior.

*(emphasis mine)*

Comment: Thank you! Extremely helpful info.

Comment: @Apple: Can we have this tintable, please! So we can keep consistency and customization at the same time!

Answer (score 11):

This answer is not a fix for the issue of `NSLinkAttributeName` ignoring custom colors, it's an alternative solution for having colored clickable words in `NSAttributedString`.

---

With this workaround we don't use `NSLinkAttributeName` at all, since it forces a style we don't want.

Instead, we use custom attributes, and we subclass the `NSTextField`/`NSTextView` to detect the attributes under the mouse click and act accordingly.

There's several constraints, obviously: you have to be able to subclass the field/view, to override `mouseDown`, etc, but "it works for me" while waiting for a fix.

When preparing your `NSMutableAttributedString`, where you would have set an `NSLinkAttributeName`, set the link as an attribute with a custom key instead:

```
theAttributedString.addAttribute("CUSTOM", value: theLink, range: theLinkRange)
theAttributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.orange, range: theLinkRange)
theAttributedString.addAttribute(NSCursorAttributeName, value: NSCursor.arrow(), range: theLinkRange)
```

The color and content for the link is set. Now we have to make it clickable.

For this, subclass your `NSTextView` and override `mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)`.

We will get the location of the mouse event in the window, find the character index in the text view at that location, and ask for the attributes of the character at this index in the text view's attributed string.

```
class MyTextView: NSTextView {

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        // the location of the click event in the window
        let point = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        // the index of the character in the view at this location
        let charIndex = self.characterIndexForInsertion(at: point)
        // if we are not outside the string...
        if charIndex < super.attributedString().length {
            // ask for the attributes of the character at this location
            let attributes = super.attributedString().attributes(at: charIndex, effectiveRange: nil)
            // if the attributes contain our key, we have our link
            if let link = attributes["CUSTOM"] as? String {
                // open the link, or send it via delegate/notification
            }
        }
        // cascade the event to super (optional)
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }

}
```

That's it.

In my case I needed to customize different words with different colors and link types, so instead of passing just the link as a string I pass a struct containing the link and additional meta information, but the idea is the same.

If you have to use an `NSTextField` instead of an `NSTextView`, it's a bit trickier to find the click event location. A solution is to create an `NSTextView` inside the `NSTextField` and from there use the same technique as before.

```
class MyTextField: NSTextField {

    var referenceView: NSTextView {
        let theRect = self.cell!.titleRect(forBounds: self.bounds)
        let tv = NSTextView(frame: theRect)
        tv.textStorage!.setAttributedString(self.attributedStringValue)
        return tv
    }

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let point = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        let charIndex = referenceView.textContainer!.textView!.characterIndexForInsertion(at: point)
        if charIndex < self.attributedStringValue.length {
            let attributes = self.attributedStringValue.attributes(at: charIndex, effectiveRange: nil)
            if let link = attributes["CUSTOM"] as? String {
                // ...
            }
        }
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Aya. I just got the solution what I am looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Great idea! I needed to add two things to make it work with text fields in the end: (1) Set the `lineFragmentPadding` of the custom text view's text container; (2) Add a paragraph style to the attributed string that has the `lineBreakMode` set to `NSLineBreakStrategyPushOut` (for >= 11.0, use `NSLineBreakStrategyStandard`).

These things fix a few glitches with multi-line labels.