# Customize color for NSLinkAttributeName in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to customize color for `NSLinkAttributeName` in UILabel. But setting `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` not affect link text color, it still blue.

But `NSUnderlineColorAttributeName` works and I was able to customize underline color. Is it possible to change link text color somehow?

Comment: Related, with interesting information from Apple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926951/color-attribute-is-ignored-in-nsattributedstring-with-nslinkattributename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had same issue when I tried to customize UILabel, and I figured, that `NSLinkAttributeName` has bigger priority than `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. Or, maybe, `NSLinkAttributeName` processed after foreground color.

I ended with cycle through all `NSLinkAttributeName` and replace it with my custom attribute with name `CustomLinkAttribute`. After that it works like a charm. And I was also able to get link, by accessing to my custom attribute

```
func setupHtmlLinkTextStyle(attributedString: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString {
    let updatedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    attributedString.enumerateAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName,
                                        in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                        options: [],
                                        using:
        {(attribute, range, stop) in
            if attribute != nil {
                var attributes = updatedString.attributes(at: range.location, longestEffectiveRange: nil, in: range)
                attributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor.green
                attributes[NSUnderlineColorAttributeName] = UIColor.green
                attributes[NSStrokeColorAttributeName] = UIColor.green
                attributes["CustomLinkAttribute"] = attribute!
                attributes.removeValue(forKey: NSLinkAttributeName)
                updatedString.setAttributes(attributes, range: range)
            }
    })
    return updatedString
}
```

Comment: Ha! But you no longer have .link attribute and link will not work.