# How can you change the color of links in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the color of a link within a UILabel. I've found loads of past questions on how to do this for a UITextView, and past questions with answers in Obj-C (but can't translate these to Swift as properties that did exist in Obj-c no longer do such as NSMutableAttributedString.linkTextAttribtues for example).
But I cannot find how to do this for a UILabel and in Swift 4.

Comment: Try this [KILabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel) it's in Objective-C bridge it and enable link detection

Comment: UIKit functionality is the same in Swift as it is in ObjC; only the names change.

Comment: Thanks but there's way way too much code there and its overkill just to set the link color. Using a sledgehammer to crack a peanut. There must be a one or two line way of doing it directly in Swift.

Comment: @Josh Caswell, looking at the declaration for UILabel and mutable attributed string, I can see nothing with a name remotely similar to something like linkTextAttributes or link similar for either of those. So what is linkTextAttributes been renamed to in Swift 4?

Comment: Not sure; I believe that's on `UITextView`, not `NSAttributedString`, but I was just trying to say that _if_ it's there in ObjC, it'll also be available in Swift.

Comment: Last I remember, you just plain _can't_ change the link styling for a label.

Comment: If you are using UILabel then perhaps you can replace those link attributes with a custom attribute as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006711/customize-color-for-nslinkattributename-in-uilabel

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For default *NSAttributedString.Key.**link*** color will be blue.
If you need custom colors for links you can set the attribute as *NSAttributedString.Key.**attachment*** instead of ***.link*** and set the foreground and underline colors like this:

```
let linkCustomAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
                            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
                            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.magenta,
                            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                            NSAttributedString.Key.attachment: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

If you need to **handle touches on links** you can use this custom label class:

```
import UIKit

public protocol UILabelTapableLinksDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func tapableLabel(_ label: UILabelTapableLinks, didTapUrl url: String, atRange range: NSRange)
}

public class UILabelTapableLinks: UILabel {

    private var links: [String: NSRange] = [:]
    private(set) var layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    private(set) var textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    private(set) var textStorage = NSTextStorage() {
        didSet {
            textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        }
    }

    public weak var delegate: UILabelTapableLinksDelegate?

    public override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            if let attributedText = attributedText {
                textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
                findLinksAndRange(attributeString: attributedText)
            } else {
                textStorage = NSTextStorage()
                links = [:]
            }
        }
    }

    public override var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode {
        didSet {
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        }
    }

    public override var numberOfLines: Int {
        didSet {
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
        }
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines  = numberOfLines
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainer.size = bounds.size
    }

    private func findLinksAndRange(attributeString: NSAttributedString) {
        links = [:]
        let enumerationBlock: (Any?, NSRange, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void = { [weak self] value, range, isStop in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            if let value = value {
                let stringValue = "\(value)"
                strongSelf.links[stringValue] = range
            }
        }
        attributeString.enumerateAttribute(.link, in: NSRange(0..<attributeString.length), options: [.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired], using: enumerationBlock)
        attributeString.enumerateAttribute(.attachment, in: NSRange(0..<attributeString.length), options: [.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired], using: enumerationBlock)
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let locationOfTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {
            return
        }
        textContainer.size = bounds.size
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: locationOfTouch, in: textContainer)
        for (urlString, range) in links where NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, range) {
            delegate?.tapableLabel(self, didTapUrl: urlString, atRange: range)
            return
        }            
    }
}
```

**Setup label in your code:**

```
customLabel.attributedText = <<Your attributed text with custom links>>
customLabel.delegate = self
```

**Implement delegate:**

```
extension YourClass: UILabelTapableLinksDelegate {
    func tapableLabel(_ label: UILabelTapableLinks, didTapUrl url: String, atRange range: NSRange) {
        print("didTapUrl: ", url)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If your label is centred, it reports glyph index even when clicking on empty space occupied by padding

Comment: Links and Labels and attributed strings are just a pain in the behind. This class just worked. Very useful. Thanks.

Comment: It's insane that this much code is needed to do something natively like this.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to use UITextView instead of UILabel and write something like:

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        .underlineColor: UIColor.red,
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct but setting `.attachment` as the url doesn't open the url, at least not for me (using iOS 13). 
The color of `.link` is not affected by the `.foregroundColor` in `NSAttributedString`, but from the `tintColor` of your `UITextView`

```
 let urlAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .link: URL(string:"https://google.com"),
                .foregroundColor: textColor,
                .underlineColor: textColor,
                .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
                .underlinColor: UIColor.green
            ]
textView.tintColor = UIColor.green
textView.attributed = urlAttributes
```

should set the text and the underline of the link to green