# iOS change the color of links for uilabel when using NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, uikit, nsattributedstring

I'm using a uilabel and adding a link to by using NSAttributedString

```
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "http://www.google.com")


    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.link: "https://www.google.com"], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 21))
    attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 21))

    label.attributedText = attributedText
    label.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

How can get the link to be another color other than the other default blue link color provided by the UIKit framework.

**Note: I do not want to use UITextView or UIWebView**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983838/how-can-you-change-the-color-of-links-in-a-uilabel

Answer (score 0):

```
let attributedText = "http://www.google.com"
        let multipleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue ]
        let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: attributedText, attributes: multipleAttributes)

        // set attributed text on a UILabel
        label.attributedText = attributeString
```