# Set color of a particular hyperlink (as opposed to all links) in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uitextview

I have two different kinds of links I want to display in a UITextView. I'd like to change the color of one kind of them. The following code successfully sets the font and text of the link, but `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is not being set as `UIColor.green`:

```
attributedText?.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Light", size:16.0)!,
                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green,
                               NSLinkAttributeName: value!],
                               range: range)
```

How can you change the color of a particular link? `UITextView.linkTextAttributes` won't do the trick because that sets the color for all links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926951/color-attribute-is-ignored-in-nsattributedstring-with-nslinkattributename. TLDR: the behavior of NSLinkAttributeName has changed.