# Html to attributed string, change link color

Tags: swift3, swift4, nsattributedstring

I am converting html to attributed string and loading it to UIlable , I am getting hyperlink color as blue, I want to change that color, please help

Comment: You need to call `enumerateAttribute(_:in:options:using:)` on the `NSAttributedStringKey.link` (Swift 4) and modify yourself the attributed at that range to the color you want.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39926951/2227743 This is about NSColor but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the link by linkTextAttributes

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```