# NSTextField NSAttributedString foregroundColor for links is broken on macOS 14

Tags: macos, hyperlink, nstextfield

I'm trying to set an attributed string to a textfield that contains a link and show this link in **red** and not in a default light blue color. MacOS seems to use`NScolor.linkColor` for links.

```
textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
textField.isSelectable = true

let urlText = "https://google.com"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: urlText)
let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.string.count) 
   
attributedString.beginEditing()
attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: urlText, range: range)
attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.red, range: range)
attributedString.endEditing()
       
// Just an outlet textfield on a cell
textField.attributedStringValue = attributedString
```

I checked the official documentation about how this should be done: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1487/_index.html
Specifically, this line:

```
// make the text appear in blue
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor blueColor] range:range];
```

It doesn't work no matter what I do. The color of the link is always the default one.
It's sad that such simple things is so hard to achieve on macOS. Maybe someone has some ideas.

Comment: The linked documentation is from 2012.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color attribute is ignored in NSAttributedString with NSLinkAttributeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926951/color-attribute-is-ignored-in-nsattributedstring-with-nslinkattributename)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for providing this link. The solution described there is a decent workaround however I had issues with cursor when using this approach. If you hover on the link, there's no way to update cursor to pointing hand. Also when you try to copy the content of the NSTextField it sometimes triggers the click event. I ended up with using NSTextView